# Creating popup messages

Tags: java, html, jsp, popup, message

I am trying to popup error messages, like in html 5 .

For example :

In this code if i enter a number less than 0 or a more than 5 , it pops up an error message.

```
  <input type="number" name="quantity" min="1" max="5">
```

This will be the pop up :

[image]

So what i want to do is i want to display a customized message of my own. 
 For example , if a user tries to log in to a system and the password is wrong, i want to popup saying "password is wrong" , without showing an error page (Which i have currently done).

How can i implement this ?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, for security reasons you don't want to admit the username is correct - the messaging should be more generic like "Please enter a valid username and password"

The other consideration is how the credentials are verified.  This could be done with a simple webservice that returns a JSON result.  So a request to: `/verifycreds.php?username=John&password=password` could return the following:

```
{ success: false, message: "Please enter a valid username and password" }
```

From there the form would be updated with an onSubmit handler to verify the credentials before submitting the page.  For this example I'll use jQuery - [please reference the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/submit/)

```
$( "#myform" ).submit(function( event ) {
    var verificationURL = "/verifycreds.php?username=" 
                          + $('#username').val() 
                          + "&password=" + $('#password').val();
    $.get(verificationURL, function(data) {
        if(!data.success) {
            event.preventDefault();
            // Display popup of your choice here with data.message
        }
    });
});
```

That is the basic setup.  We are adding an onSubmit handler to `#myForm`, we build the URL to the verify credentials webservice, we then handle the result and stop the form submission if verification fails and show the message.